# How to select rows in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, row, pandas-datareader

I have a csv like:

```
1. [Book; Value]

2.[Expenses_b; 500]

3. [Expenses; 1000]

4. [Cash; 900]
```

I need to select the rows that match with book = Expenses and Expenses_b. I can select them separately, as the example:

> import pandas as pd
>
> data = pd.read_csv(r'path', sep='\t')
> Expenses = data[data.Book == 'Expenses' ]

Is that any way I can select both of them together or rows that contain 'Expenses'?

Comment: `data.Book.str.contains('Expenses')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by using str method on the given series.

```
expenses = data[data.Book.str.contains("Expenses")]
```